# Celery Add new tasks dinamically

Tags: celery, celerybeat

Is it possible to schedule a task in celery from another task?

I've got this Python script:

```
import logging
from celery import Celery
from datetime import datetime

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

app = Celery('app', backend='amqp://', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost:5672//')

@app.task()
def add(x, y):
    result = x + y
    logger.info(f'Add: {x} + {y} = {result}')
    return result

@app.task()
def setPeriodicTask():
     #option 1 
    app.add_periodic_task(10, add.s(30, 1))
     #option 2 
    app.conf.beat_schedule = {
        'add-every-5-seconds': {
            'task': 'app.add',
            'schedule': 5.0,
            'args': (now.hour, now.second)
        }
    }
    logger.info(f'setPeriodicTask succeeded')
    return 1
```

When I call the add task, it works OK.

If I call the setPeriodicTask task it does not throw any error but the add task is not scheduled.
I've tried both options, none is working:

1. add_periodic_task
2. modify the beat_schedule

If I add this code to my Python script (as I've seen in the celery docs):

```
@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(5.0, add.s(10, 1))
```

I can see the add task running scheduled as expected. So celery and celery beat seem to be working fine.
But I want to enable/disable the task on demand.

Is it possible? And if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I know you can't configure scheduler from a task. That needs do be done at the same place where you do other configuration related stuff. Basically, `setPeriodicTask()` will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else faces this issue.

I ended up using a database with a similar approach as the one mention in the django -celery-beat doc: [django-celery-beat - Database-backed Periodic Tasks](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)